# How to use sortedcontainers.SortedList with SQLAlchemy relationship()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database with a many-to-one relation. In my declarative system, I have a call to [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html?highlight=relationship#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship)() as in the following minimal example. For some reason, I want to keep all `Features` sorted. Unfortunately, the sorting logic is quite complicated and done using several attributes.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text)

class Feature(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'features'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    productid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'))
    attr = Column(Integer)

    product = relationship('Product', back_populates='features')
    Product.features=relationship('Feature', collection_class=SortedList, back_populates='product')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # some magic here, simplified...
        return self.attr == other.attr

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # some magic here, simplified...
        return self.attr < other.attr

    def __le__(self, other):
        # some magic here, simplified...
        return self.attr <= other.attr

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I have a database already filled with the following values:

```
sqlite> select * from products;
id          name      
----------  ----------
1           Product1  
sqlite> select * from features;
id          productid   attr      
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           42        
2           1           1
```

When I try to load (by accessing) those values, sortedcontainers.SortedList raises a ValueError exception, presumably because it is trying to load unordered results. When features are stored ordered, there is no problem.

```
In [1]: from test import *
In [2]: session = Session()
In [3]: p = session.query(Product).first()
In [4]: for f in p.features:
    print("id: %d\tattr: %d" % (f.id, f.attr))
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
# traceback
ValueError: <test.Feature object at 0x7f68da5d2208> not in sort order at index 1
```

I know in this particular case, the solution is to use `relationship`() with argument `order_by` but my use case is more complicated since sorting uses the values of several columns.

So, is there something I missed using SQLAlchemy or should I try to find a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I finally found a very simple solution looking at the backtrace:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py in append(self, item, _sa_initiator)
   1072         def append(self, item, _sa_initiator=None):
   1073             item = __set(self, item, _sa_initiator)
-> 1074             fn(self, item)
   1075         _tidy(append)
   1076         return append

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.py in append(self, val)
   1026         if val < _lists[pos][-1]:
   1027             msg = '{0} not in sort order at index {1}'.format(repr(val), self._len)
-> 1028             raise ValueError(msg)
   1029 
   1030         _maxes[pos] = val
```

Obviously, we are calling `append` on the `SortedList`. From the [documentation](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#id1), `append` raises a ValueError if the value violates the sort order.

Basically the solution is to override that method:

```
class SuperSortedList(SortedList):
    def append(self, item):
        self.add(item)
```

That seems to work even on my real life example. It might be a good idea to override all methods of that kind (e.g. `insert`), though.